# Asciidoctor : How to add nested list across rows in a table

Tags: asciidoctor

I have a requirement to develop table in adoc format with nested lists across rows in first column

Expected output table: with nested bullets
[expected output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr7sB.png)

Any suggestions? intent to have first column with hierarchical intended rows
Thank you in advance

Tried below code in .adoc file. But nesting of list across rows is not happening.
[Tested code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuzvJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use code blocks instead of screenshots to express what you expect and what you have tried for future reference.

Your tested code and expected output differ, so it is not clear whether the following solutions are what you want.

Your expected output shows that you want asterisks to appear, and the amount of indent seems to be based solely on the number of asterisks. If that's accurate, then do this:

```
= Document
:star: *

[cols="<2a,<2"]
|===
| One
| Two

|
{star} IP1

| Data1

|
{star}{star} SubIP1

| Data 2
|===
```

That renders like this:

[image]

However, you must change your strategy if you need to show bullets indented in separate cells as part of a nested list in a single cell (or outside of the table). AsciiDoc provides no way to start a bulleted list at a specific depth.

One thing you could try is making content that looks like it is a list, but it is not:

```
= Document

:bullet: &bull;
:indent: {nbsp}{nbsp}

[cols="<2a,<2"]
|===
| One
| Two

| {bullet} IP1
| Data1

| {indent}{bullet} SubIP1
| Data 2

|===
```

That renders like this:

[image]

You must repeat the `{indent}` attribute for additional nesting.